# I cannot login from Dockered Django web application. What is wrong?

Tags: django, sqlite, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I successfully put my web application in a Docker container. Looking through...

- I can register users. When I tried to register the same user my web application says that the user is already registered.
- I cannot logged in as any users.
- I can go to admin login panel.
- I cannot logged in as an admin.
- Other than that everything went fine.

I am using SQLite. And this is my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "3"  
services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_airport
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  rabbit:
      hostname: rabbit_airport
      image: rabbitmq:latest
      environment:
          - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
          - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=asdasdasd
      ports:
          - "5673:5672"
  web:
    build: ./
    container_name: django_airport
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./static:/app/static
    expose:
      - "8080"
    links:
        - rabbit
    depends_on:
        - rabbit
```

I don't think I need separate container for SQLite don't I?

Comment: do you have any logs?

Comment: The logs only comes from RabbitMQ, https://pastebin.com/HkYH7H2c. How can I see the log from Django?

Comment: There are logs for Django (line 159 - 164) which says that is spawning 3 processes. If you do a docker ps the django container is there or?

Comment: Yes there are three running container as I expected, RabbitMQ, NGINX, and my web application itself. As I mentioned before the website went fine, other than I cannot login for some reason. There is no error in the console side though.

Comment: if you do docker logs -f [ django-container-id ] and try to login can you see anything?

Comment: Hey should I activate the `DEBUG=True` because I ran my Django application with Gunicorn. I supposed the problem lies in the container? Because without Docker it is working.

Comment: i guess you could give it a go :)

Comment: Now it has 502 bad gateway when I turned the DEBUG off.